# Make Visual Studio's CMake tool run INSTALL when build solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017

My VS2017 is using CMake 3.9.2 internally. I tried to build a C++ CMake project with `Right click folder -> Open in Visual Studio -> Menu bar: CMake -> Build solution`, unfortunately it didn't run `INSTALL`.

But when I used the default program CMake GUI to generate a visual studio solution, and then ran `Build All`. After building, it also ran the `INSTALL` project just fine.

I have set:

```
set(CMAKE_VS_INCLUDE_INSTALL_TO_DEFAULT_BUILD 1)
```

How could I make Visual Studio run `INSTALL` after building?

Answer (score 2):

The INSTALL target of the Visual Studio solution depends by default on the ALL_BUILD target. So if you choose to "Set Startup Project" to INSTALL your solution will build and install.